# Is two way 1-n relationship between classes acceptable?

Tags: oop

I met a problem like this.

class A have a list of class B.   A have choose one of B, and call its method.  So A depends on B.

But when a timer ( not a real timer, just a mimic clock ) fires, B have to tell A that "I am done", so A can choose another B to work, which means B has to know A also.

This is a "two way 1-n relationship" and I think A and B are not well seperated.

Of course I can use Observer Pattern and make A an observer and B a subject, but this is not a typical case where observer pattern make sense because there is only one observer.

What do u think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A knows about the available Bs. B only knows about the A currently using him. I don't think that's 1-n is it?

But B doesn't depend upon A as such, he does not care it's an A. He just needs to use the "finished()" method of his temprary associate. There's no real dependency there.

```
Class A implements ClientOfB {
       Collection<B> myBees;

       public beNottified() { ...}

       public employeeBee () {
             myBees.getRandomBee().buzz(this);
       }
```

}

```
Class B {
    public void buzz(ClientOfB client) {
          client.beNotified();
    }
}
```

I don't see unreasonable dependencies. A needs to know about buzz and to expose an interface. B only knows about the interface.

Comment: This makes sense to me.  B could remove it's reference to A after buzz is called.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with n8wrl that an event is probably a cleaner solution.

Original answer:

Does B need to know about all possible A's or just the one that called it (the one it tells "I am Done")?   If so, then A can have the list of All B's, and B can have a reference to only the one A that matters.

Here's how I'd do it.  Yes there's a cyclic association, but there's some control in how it's used.  And this can eventually be refactored to a purer observer pattern if required.

```
class A
{
  List<B> bObj = new List<B>();

  public void callB(/*Params*/)
  {
    B bThatMatters = //Find Appropriate B ...
    bThatMatters.DoStuff(this);
  }

  public void isDone()
  {
     //Handle being done with the last B
  }
}

class B
{
   A _callerA;

   public void DoStuff(A callerA)
   {
      _callerA = callerA;

     //... DO STUFF
   }

 public void WhenDone()
 {
    _callerA.isDone()
 }
}
```

Comment: An event is only a good answer if he has that abstraction in a library or the language itself. The question makes no assumption about language so even though you used C# it's still a good answer.

Comment: At this moment, B only needs to know the one who calls it -- because only A have the list of B and only A know which one to call next.

I think this is the natural solution now.  That's also what came to my mine when I met this problem.

----

Maybe use some abstract class for A and B will make it cleaner.

Comment: I am using python, so event is not choice.

BTW : event is also an implementation of observer pattern, at least in C#

Comment: And one thing makes me skeptic to observer pattern (and event) is that it makes a lot of cylic reference. 

For example, when I need to drop A, I have to first go over list of B and remove all their reference to A.

I think C# now support weak reference when make event binding, but when I worked with C#, I have to remove all these cylce references by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I've been working in C# for the past few months so I had forgotten that not all languages support events.

Observer is useful when you need it.  In this case, you don't need it, so why have the extra complexity?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one observer NOW, but who knows in the future?

A gets a B. B exposes an event that A (or anyone else for that matter) subscribes to. B fires the event, A gets the message.

B does not know about A it only knows about its own event.